# electron js: how to import custom js in renderer.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I try this in renderer.js

```
import * as math from './math.js'
```

I get error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Do you have `type="module"` on a script tag that loads `renderer.js`

Comment: Thanks, I add this and now it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to comment I solve this.
I add `type="module"` and change to

```
const math = require("./math.js")
```